# NestJS WebSocket Message Format

Tags: typescript, websocket, nestjs, ws

I am trying to implement a WebSocket server with ws (not socket.io) and based on these answers from StackOverflow, WebSocket messages must be in the format {event: "eventname', data: {data}} :

[SubcribeMessage decorator doesn't trigger on event 'message'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67282484/subcribemessage-decorator-doesnt-trigger-on-event-message)

[Messages not reaching handler while using WebSocket and nestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73592745/messages-not-reaching-handler-while-using-websocket-and-nestjs)

I was wondering if there is a way to bypass this and/or if there is any official documentation regarding this.

Since the messages I am currently receiving from the server are in a fixed format, it would be nice to know if there is any more info on this. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was getting WebSocket messages from Twilio when streaming call audio but Twilio doesn't use the `ws` package's format. My solution was to extend the `WsAdapter` and overwrite the `bindMessageHandler` function to ensure the `data` field was present.

```
// custom-ws-adapter.ts
import { MessageMappingProperties } from '@nestjs/websockets/gateway-metadata-explorer';
import { EMPTY, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { WsAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-ws';

export class CustomWsAdapter extends WsAdapter {
  // taken from https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/platform-ws/adapters/ws-adapter.ts
  public bindMessageHandler(
    buffer: any,
    handlers: MessageMappingProperties[],
    transform: (data: any) => Observable<any>,
  ): Observable<any> {
    try {
      const message = JSON.parse(buffer.data);
      const messageHandler = handlers.find(
        handler => handler.message === message.event,
      );
      const { callback } = messageHandler;

      // BEGIN MODIFIED CODE
      // This is needed since the ws library expects {event: string; data: any} formatting
      // but Twilio's call streams don't have the data field
      if (!message.data) {
        message.data =  { ...message, event: undefined }
      }
      // END MODIFIED CODE

      return transform(callback(message.data, message.event));
    } catch {
      return EMPTY;
    }
  }
}

// in main.ts
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.useWebSocketAdapter(new CustomWsAdapter(app))
```

Comment: Before trying this approach, I'd already tried a [NestJS middleware](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware) but that seemed to only work for HTTP request and not WS requests. I also tried a [NestJS interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) but I couldn't access the original request since the adapter had already modified it to the `ws` format of `{event: string; data: any}`. This solution was the only one that gave me access to modifying the incoming request's format.